# BeagleBone Black UART 1 config

Tags: linux, drivers, serial-port, beagleboneblack, device-tree

Recently I compiled my own linux system using kernel 5.10.23, and I made modifications to the device tree in order to activate UART 1 PIN (9-24) and (9-26).

I have /dev/ttyS1 available for R/W operations and when I do

```
dmesg | grep serial
```

I got

```
[    2.945152] 44e09000.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x44e09000 (irq = 20, base_baud = 3000000) is a 8250
[    3.685189] 48022000.serial: ttyS1 at MMIO 0x48022000 (irq = 26, base_baud = 3000000) is a 8250
[    3.703783] msm_serial: driver initialized
```

I tried to debug using a logic analyser so when I do

```
echo "TEST" > /dev/ttyS1
```

I got nothing

This is the device tree that i modified 
PS: i reversed the DTS from the system available on the eMMC of the BBB and i activated the Uart ports

```
serial@0 {
    compatible = "ti,am3352-uart\0ti,omap3-uart";
    clock-frequency = < 0x2dc6c00 >;
    reg = < 0x00 0x1000 >;
    interrupts = < 0x49 >;
    status = "okay";
    dmas = < 0x21 0x1c 0x00 0x21 0x1d 0x00 >;
    dma-names = "tx\0rx";
    };
```

Any ideas why ?

Comment: Did you *configure* the UART? Especially, setting a baud rate would be important. Also, you made modifications – would make sense to add them to your question!

Comment: hello marcus, yes i did using #stty -F /dev/ttyS1 9600 raw -echo

Comment: device tree modifications in your question, still, please!

Comment: they are replies

Comment: Make sure `/dev/ttyS1` exists and is a character device with correct major/minor numbers (`ls -l /dev/ttyS1`), then try `(stty raw -echo 9600; echo "TEST") </dev/ttyS1 >/dev/ttyS1` (i.e. prevent opening and closing of the device file multiple times) ... also you might need to modify some sort of pin configuration to connect the uart to the pins (e.g. multiplexed pins).